# How to write bellow code in Laravel? (this code written using MySQL)

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
SELECT  empID,
        SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( SUBTIME(out_time,in_time) ) ) ) AS timeSum
```

I want to get the total working hours of employees in one month. I used the above code in MySQL. But I need to know how to use this query in Laravel

Comment: You will probably need a native query in Laravel to do this.

Comment: how can I use it? can you give me an example of that?

Comment: `$users = DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$results = DB::query()
    ->select(
        'empID',
        DB::raw('SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(SUBTIME(out_time,in_time)))) AS timeSum')
    )
    ->from('employees')
    ->get();
```

Comment: i want to get only hours. how can i do it?